# Add class to ancestor of current item with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this format

```
<dl>
<dd>
  <div>
    <div>
      <a>
```

I have added a click event to  with

```
 $("dl dd div div a").click()
```

How can I add a class to current dd element

Something like

```
$(this).ancestors("dd").addClass("x")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)

Try:

```
$("dl dd div div a").click(function () {
    $(this).parents("dd").addClass("x");
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5kngL/)

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> *Description:* For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

```
$(this).closest("dd").addClass("x");
```